# Apply padding on a html page via CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to apply `padding-bottom:90px;` so I can move [Tweets by ‎@StackOverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWIF3.png) (The whole tweets area) down the page.

*I.e. further down, with the above padding, however, this is not working for me, how would I achieve this?*

I don't want to use line breaks tags `<br>`, however, this does add line breaks tho, anyway I want to do it achieve moving the Tweets section via CSS. In addition to this I did add a `<div class="twitterwrapper">` however this didn't still work.

**Below is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .twitterwrapper{
            padding-bottom:90px;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="twitterwrapper">
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="400" data-height="500" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#E81C4F" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" data-chrome="nofooter noborders transparent">Tweets by stackoverflow</a>
                <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should use `padding-top`

Comment: `margin-top` would be better.

Comment: Could you show the full (relevant) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:-

```
.twitterwrapper{

padding-top:90px;
background-color: lightblue;

}
```

Comment: Take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_padding-top

Answer (score 0):

Either add padding-top or negative margin, since there is no content in the code you provided, I can't imagine what exactly you're trying to achive. If you want to make "an ad" use margin and position to achive your expected results.

Comment: negative padding take no effect. Padding is zero and positive values only. The default value of zero will be in effect

Comment: I know that, I was trying to type negative margin but was in hurry.. :/